# Adding a column using swift and parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

My intention is to create a new column for a string that users determine while signing up.

Through the dashboard, I added a new column for this string called "birthcountry".

I tried using the new column in xcode

```
     let myUser = PFUser()
     myUser.username = userEmail
     myUser.password = userPassword
     myUser.email = userEmail
     myUser.birthcountry = birthcountry
```

And I got the error:

"Value of type 'pfuser' has no member 'birthcountry' "

Comment: how should Xcode dynamically know at compile time that in some arbitrary backend you added a new column? Try setting the data it via `myUser["birthcountry"] = birthcountry` instead.

Comment: thanks, just what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how should Xcode dynamically know at compile time that in some arbitrary backend you added a new column? Try setting the data it via myUser["birthcountry"] = birthcountry instead. – luk2302

Answer (score 0):

Try writing 
let myUser= PFuser()

Myuser.setValue(useremail, forKey: "username")
                                                    Myuser.setValue(userPassword, forKey: "password")
etc...

Or are you trying to download values from parse?